# I am trying to model Y by X where Y is count data using a quasipoisson model. It doesn't seem to be fitting the data well

Tags: regression, poisson-regression

The data structure is that Y is count data and x is a continuous variable.

Here is scatterplot of my data and the quasi-poisson model fit overlayed. I attempted two model fits - quasipoisson with the `glm` function and a poisson model with `glmnet` method in `caret` package with poisson family.

```
model_red <- glm(y ~ x, data = data, family = quasipoisson)
model_green <- caret::train(y ~ x, data = data,
             method = "glmnet",
             family = "poisson")
```

The model doesn't appear to be capturing the data well as x gets larger. Do you believe a quasi-poisson model is correct in this case?
[image: Model overlayed data] I'm afraid that my model is underestimating and not capturing the true underlying trend. Am I doing the correct steps to model this relationship and I'm just overthinking the fit?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here is an idea, perhaps you are not overthinking but instead not precisely understanding what you are observing. In essence, you have a mixture of processes and have only been aware of one for which you proposed a model.

Comment: Hi @jackbio, could you please add a plot of the density (or histogram) of y?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that you need to consider a different handling of the `x` variable. With the implicit log link, your model simply treats the log of `y` as a linear function of `x`. Just as with ordinary least squares, you might need to use some transformation of `x` to capture the relationship better. Your knowledge of the subject matter might suggest such a transformation.